# ctrl alt h shortut not being caught by my active program anymore

Tags: keyboard, leopard, ui

this is what I get when pressing that combo. Also, some strange window frame gets drawn along the active sub-windows... I do not know how I have managed to screw it like that but would surey like to revert to normal. Help please

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's VoiceOver, an accessibility tool. Go to System Preferences → Universal Access → Seeing, and set **VoiceOver** to **Off**.